# Unable make wxWidgets-3.0.4 on codeblocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks, wxwidgets

I am facing a problem when I try to install the wxWidgets-3.0.4 and used it with Code::Blocks. I have searched a lot on the internet for something similar, without success.

I had installed the wxWidgets in the directory C:\wxWidgets-3.0.4
I used the instructions from the site [here](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/CodeBlocks_Setup_Guide) but when I type

```
mingw32-make.exe -f makefile.gcc USE_XRC=1 SHARED=1 MONOLITHIC=1 BUILD=release UNICODE=0
```

I get

---

```
C:\wxWidgets-3.0.4\build\msw>mingw32-make.exe -f makefile.gcc USE_XRC=1 SHARED=1 MONOLITHIC=1 BUILD=release UNICODE=0
if not exist ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\msw mkdir ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\msw
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, -c "if not exist ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\msw mkdir ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\msw", ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
makefile.gcc:5642: recipe for target '..\..\lib\gcc_dll\msw' failed
mingw32-make.exe: *** [..\..\lib\gcc_dll\msw] Error 2
```

So, I cannot figure out the problem. Why I cannot continue.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have some Cygwin/MSYS utilities in your `PATH` and they don't work with these makefiles which are explicitly intended for being used from DOS-like environments.

If you want to use Cygwin, you should build wxWidgets using configure. Otherwise, type `path` to see the current value and remove anything containing `mkdir.exe` from it.